# Dell PowerEdge T520, PERC H310 RAID 1, can I hot swap a HDD without shutting down the server?

Tags: raid1, dell-perc, hotswap

I have a Dell Poweredge T520 running Win Server 2008 Rc2 with a PERC H310 RAID Controller. Two 15000 rpm 600GB hard drives setup in RAID 1. One drive is rapid flashing orange indicating failure. Can I take out the failed drive and hot swap a new identical drive in without shutting down the server, and it rebuild? Do I have to preformat the new drive or simply just pop in the new one after inserting into the carriage?

Thanks

[image: PERC H310]

[image: Perc H310 2]

Answer (score 2):

**Hot swap** refers to the controller/disk ability to be swapped *with the OS running*, without causing downtime.

On the other hand, your screenshot are taken in the controller's BIOS screen: this means that you *can* shutdown/reboot the machine. In other words, you don't need any hotswap capability.

From [DELL H310 manual](http://www.flagshiptech.com/eBay/Dell/poweredgeh310h710h810UsersGuide.pdf):

> **Replacing An Online Physical Disk**
>   In addition to the automatic Replace
>   Member operation, you can manually replace any physical disk that is
>   part of a virtual disk using the Replace Member functionality.
> Perform
>   the following steps to replace a physical disk:
>   1. In the Virtual Disk Management window, select Virtual Disk # and press the down-arrow key until Physical Disks is highlighted.
>   2. Press the right-arrow key to expand the list of physical disks that are members of the virtual disk.
>   3. Press the down-arrow key and highlight the desired physical disk you want to replace. Press  to expand the list of allowed
>   operations on the disk.
>   4. Select Replace and then Start.
>   5. Press the down-arrow to highlight a replacement disk and then press the spacebar to select the disk.
>   6. Select OK to start the replacement.

Anyway, do yourself a favor and read the manual **before** doing anything.

Comment: I guess thanks for the time you took to type out your answer and look up the manual. I am a manager of a very busy architectural paint store and if I had time to read the manual, I would not have come here seeking quick, accurate advice. I know what hot swapping is, as should have been indicated in my question. I added the screenshot to perhaps give an expert in these matters a clearer picture of my hardware involving my RAID setup. I do not want to reboot as the server in question runs the store Point of sale.

Comment: Hi, albeit I understand that asking here is quicker than reading the relevant manual, I **strongly** suggest you against doing any IT related without a clear understanding of the underlying tech. If you server is under an active support contract, call DELL and ask them for details about the disk substitution.